# LNK2001 trying to use v8 from Visual Studio C++CLI project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, v8

When building a simple hello-world-style project trying to embed v8 I get an

> error LNK2001: ""public: static class v8::Local __cdecl v8::String::New(char const *,int)" (?New@String@v8@@SA?AV?$Local@VString@v8@@@2@PEBDH@Z)"

Something's wrong with my project settings and I can't seem to figure it out. This is my source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "v8.h"

using namespace System;

#pragma unmanaged

void test()
{
    v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::New("'Hello' + ', World'");
}

#pragma managed

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling seems to work fine, I added the v8 directory of the node 0.8.0 project (node-v0.8.0\deps\v8\include). In terms of linking, I added these libs as additional dependencies.

```
node-v0.8.0\Release\lib\v8_base.lib
node-v0.8.0\Release\lib\v8_snapshot.lib
```

I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit. My project is set to build x64, as is node.js (installed using the 'Windows x64 installer'). What's wrong?

**Update** I figured that when building for x64, the additional dependencies I added are completely ignored (the error messages are the same whether I add them or not). But when building for win32, I get different error messages. (Btw: Does that mean the lib files are for x86 and not x64 - as I assumed - and why didn't the linker tell me so? **Update**: dumpbin told me, the lib files are indeed for x86).

In addition to v8_base and v8_snapshot, the linker errors lead me to add

```
winmm.lib
ws2_32.lib
```

Which gets rid of all "unresolved external symbol" errors. But now I get a LNK2005 "already defined" error:

```
エラー 1   error LNK2005: __matherr は既に LIBCMT.lib(_matherr_.obj) で定義されています。   c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCRTD.lib(merr.obj)  HelloC++CLIWorld
```

I tried `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT`, then I get an LNK2001 "unresolved external symbol":

```
エラー 1   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "__HUGE" は未解決です。  c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\v8_base.lib(heap.obj)  HelloC++CLIWorld
```

I also tried  `/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD', but then I get tons of LNK2001s again. A tiny selection:

```
エラー 1   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "___native_dllmain_reason" は未解決です。    c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) HelloC++CLIWorld
エラー 2   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "___native_vcclrit_reason" は未解決です。    c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) HelloC++CLIWorld
エラー 3   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "___native_startup_state" は未解決です。 c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) HelloC++CLIWorld
エラー 4   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "___native_startup_lock" は未解決です。  c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCMRTD.lib(mstartup.obj) HelloC++CLIWorld
エラー 5   error LNK2001: 外部シンボル ""extern "C" int __cdecl __wgetmainargs(int *,wchar_t * * *,wchar_t * * *,int,struct _startupinfo *)" (?__wgetmainargs@@$$J0YAHPAHPAPAPA_W1HPAU_startupinfo@@@Z)" は未解決です。 c:\...\HelloC++CLIWorld\HelloC++CLIWorld\MSVCMRTD.lib(ManagedMain.obj)  HelloC++CLIWorld
```

Now what?

Comment: And a second, more personal question, if I may: Am I really THAT stupid? As a seasoned developer who has played with Pascal, C, x86 asm two decades ago as a kid and spent more than a decade doing mainly Java and C# for a living, and a bunch of other languages, how comes I am struggling with a simple hello world style app (and heck, I'm not even trying to print the string, just creating it!) for three solid hours? I must be stupid! (A simple confirmation is fine, too)

Comment: "trying to use V8 from C++/CLI" isn't exactly what most of us would consider a "simple hello world style app".

Comment: Is the fact that I am using CLI part of the problem?

Comment: @jalf I checked a simple C++ project without CLI. The problems were the same as with CLI. But after switching to from X64 to Win32 (see my updated question) and adding winmm.lib and ws2_32.lib it worked in C++. In CLI however I get an LNK2005 (because of additional libs necessary for CLI?)

Comment: I hate static linking. Just out of curiosity, what happens when you use a path that doesn't have `++` in its name? And `/NDEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT` seems to be a bit optimistic, [there's a lot of libraries to ignore with `/NODEFAULTLIB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @ta.speot.is solved it, see my answer. it was not the '+' characters in the folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out 2 things:

- Visual Studio will not complain about the wrong architecture in a lib file you add to the linker settings as additional dependencies, but just ignore the file (I think I'm running at the default warning levels)
- using `dumpbin mylib.lib /headers|more` revealed that the libs I thought were built for x64 were in fact built for x86

As written in the *Update* part of my question, I could not get an x86 build to work, due to `LNK2005` errors, but linking worked when I built for x64 against a x64 v8 lib (or rather, node.lib, which contains v8).

The bad news: After having managed the compilation step, and now the linking step, I get a runtime exception, even when I, as I'm supposed to do, do a

```
HandleScope handle_scope;
```

before new'ing the `v8::String`. But that's for another question. For now, linking is solved, at least on x64. Oh happy day!